# Download list of files using php, each files sepratly

Tags: php

Well obviously I have a list of *.txt files that the user( a student) will download, I have searched for many solutions but didn't find the one that would work with my code, or at least with a clear explination to what is happening as I am still discovering PHP. so basicly the page needs to be a table that includes various links to files that are uploaded to the data base( which I already did) and the student should find this list of txt files to download from. I don't have any code in this yet

Comment: have you tried the html solution? `<a href="linktofile" download="optionalfilenamehere" >click here to download</a>` ?

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)